# How to convert from HighLevelGraph to regular dask dict

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have some code like:

```
x = delayed(add)(3, 2)
y = delayed(add)(x, x)
```

and I want to get the resulting dask graph as:

```
dsk = {
    'x': (add, 3, 2),
    'y': (add, 'x', 'x')
}
```

But instead I am getting a `HighLevelGraph` as follows:

```
{'x': {'x': (add, 3, 2)},
 'y': {'y': (add,'x','x')}}
```

My question is: Is there a way to convert from the HighLevelGraph dict to the regular dict easily?

**Note**: Actual key and callables replaced with shorter equivalents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Call `dict` on it.

```
dsk = dict(dsk)
```

You can do this with any object that inherits from `Mapping`, the superclass of dict-like objects.